# How can I get closed-captions embedded inside mp4 file with VideoJS?

Tags: video.js

I want to use VideoJS in my project, and I also need closed-caption support. I have read the VideoJS docs on how to use a text-track from a WebVTT file, but most of my .mp4 files have captions embedded in the file itself, there is no WebVTT file available. How can I get the captions out of the mp4 using VideoJS?

Edit: We will be live-streaming video, which is why the closed-captions are embedded into a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the extraction step, you don't/can't use VideoJS itself. Instead, there are various standalone video editors that can do the job...just do a google-search like 'video tools to extract sub-titles'. Preferably, find/use a tool that extracts subtitles/captions into an "SRT" file-type. Then, to convert into VTT files, there are various tools for that, too. [ For that step,I use the free SRT->VTT converter avail at: http://atelier.u-sub.net/srt2vtt ]